# How to search deleted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

There are obvious questions and answers about deleted answers and saying deleted answers, which were deleted by moderators, cannot be undeleted.

But I wanted to know how I can see my recently deleted answers?

How can I search for deleted answers **which I've deleted myself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit your profile page's answer section you will see a link to `deleted recent answers`. Clicking on this link will display deleted answer like below image ( of mine recent deleted answer ),

> [image]

This list displayed only those answer which are not older than 60 days.